# MySQL table with key/value pairs, get keys as column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database where I can do the following query:

```
mysql> SELECT Name, Value from info WHERE ID = 110506;

+-------+-----------+
| Name  | Value     |
+-------+-----------+
| start | 228196    |
| stop  | 228318    |
| fwd   | 0         | 
+-------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am trying to construct a query where the result would be

```
+--------+--------+-----+
| start  | stop   | fwd |
+--------+--------+-----+
| 228196 | 228318 | 0   |
+------- +--------+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I do not know in advance what the names in my name column will be, so I need to somehow dynamically set them from the result of my `SELECT`query. How do I do that?

Comment: Its best to do this in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'start' THEN value END) AS `start`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'stop' THEN value END) AS `stop`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'fwd' THEN value END) AS `fwd`
FROM info
WHERE id = 110506;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE` ... `WHEN` clause on the column values and use the same value as column name for the resulting set. And you have to apply an aggregate function to summarize the results into a single row.

Following example uses `MAX` aggregate function to summarise the results.

```
select
    max( case `name` when 'start' then `value` end ) as `start`
  , max( case `name` when 'stop' then `value` end ) as `stop`
  , max( case `name` when 'fwd' then `value` end ) as `fwd`
from `table_name`
;
```