# How to transform a MySQL table into another that has key value pairs?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-migration

I have to accomplish a requirement in MySQL, where I need to convert a regular table into another one with key value pairs, for which I am unable to find any answers (I'm relatively new to SQL).

I've been able to find answers for the approach that's exactly opposite of my requirement though - here's a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059242/mysql-table-with-key-value-pairs-get-keys-as-column-names).

As part of the database migration activity in my project, the source table currently looks something like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM employee;
+------+-------+--------+
| id   | fname | lname  |
+------+-------+--------+
| 1    | Lex   | Luthor |
| 2    | Clark | Kent   |
| 3    | Lois  | Lane   |
+------+-------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, this has to be converted into a table that looks something like below:

```
+----------------+-----------------+
| attribute_name | attribute_value |
+----------------+-----------------+
| id             | 1               |
| fname          | Lex             |
| lname          | Luthor          |
| id             | 2               |
| fname          | Clarke          |
| lname          | Kent            |
| id             | 3               |
| fname          | Lois            |
| lname          | Lane            |
+----------------+-----------------+
```

I've tried and gotten till the below query but results aren't quite there yet.

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> T.COLUMN_NAME AS attribute_name,
    -> CASE T.COLUMN_NAME
    -> WHEN 'id' THEN employee.id
    -> WHEN 'fname' THEN employee.fname
    -> WHEN 'lname' THEN employee.lname
    -> END AS attribute_value
    -> FROM employee, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS T WHERE T.COLUMN_NAME IN
    -> (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'data_migration_test_destination' AND TABLE_NAME = 'employee');                         
+----------------+-----------------+
| attribute_name | attribute_value |
+----------------+-----------------+
| ID             | 1               |
| ID             | 1               |
| id             | 1               |
| fname          | Lex             |
| lname          | Luthor          |
| id             | 1               |
| fname          | Lex             |
| lname          | Luthor          |
| id             | 1               |
| ID             | 2               |
| ID             | 2               |
| id             | 2               |
| fname          | Clark           |
| lname          | Kent            |
| id             | 2               |
| fname          | Clark           |
| lname          | Kent            |
| id             | 2               |
| ID             | 3               |
| ID             | 3               |
| id             | 3               |
| fname          | Lois            |
| lname          | Lane            |
| id             | 3               |
| fname          | Lois            |
| lname          | Lane            |
| id             | 3               |
+----------------+-----------------+
27 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Not really sure why something like ID pops up in the result and why there are multiple repetitions for other key value pairs (id, fname and lname). Ideally the expected row count has to be 9, but I get 27!

Comment: Just GROUP BY both columns

Comment: Nik, was the below answer of any use? If so, please consider accepting it, by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
                mysql>  CREATE TABLE #Test
                    (
                        [id] INT,
                        fname  NVARCHAR(60),
                        lname NVARCHAR(60)
                    )
                    INSERT INTO #Test VALUES 
                    (1,          'Lex',     'Luthor'),
                    (2,          'Clark',     'Kent'),
                    (3,          'Lois',    'Lane')


                    select * from #Test

                    select T2.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as [Key],
                           T2.N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
                    from (select *
                          from #Test
                          for xml path(''), type) as T1(X)
                      cross apply T1.X.nodes('/*') as T2(N)


                    drop table #Test
```

Comment: You missed the mysql tag